# Got this limit over here, been working on it for a while, thought it’s time to share it with you all

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Got this limit I’d thought I should share it. So here you go:

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{x}{\big(1+\frac{i}{x}\big)}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{x}}}$$

I have worked on this one for a while, with different angles and ended up with two different answers. Would like to see how you handled it.

Comment: Most. Uninformative. Title. Ever. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Its logarithm is a Riemann sum.

Comment: On Riemann sum, Can you explain a little further?

Comment: I can and I will not.

Comment: What why not? Come onnn

Answer (score 0):

$$y={\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{x}{\big(1+\frac{i}{x}\big)}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{x}}}$$
$$y^x=\prod_{i=1}^{x}{\big(1+\frac{i}{x}\big)}$$
$$\log(y^x)=x \log(y)=\log{\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{x}{\big(1+\frac{i}{x}\big)}\bigg)}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\log\left(1+\frac i x\right)$$
$$\log(y)=\frac 1 x \sum_{i=1}^\infty\log\left(1+\frac i x\right)$$